# Timer event changes cursor

Tags: apache-flex, timer, cursor, flicker

I have a timer event that updates certain things in my app (from a PHP Service) every 5 seconds.  Every time this timer ticks, it makes the cursor blink to a clock and then back to the arrow.  Since this is happening every 5 seconds, it gets pretty annoying.  Is there a way for me to prevent the cursor from changing when the timer ticks?

UPDATE: I've figured out a work-around by setting a custom cursor with high priority (I just made a .png with a cursor in it).  This works, but the cursor doesn't seem to move as smoothly as normal.  Anyone know of a better solution?

Comment: Check your HTTP services and make sure they don't have the showBusyCursor="true" attribute.

Comment: I'm a noob when it comes to Flash...where are my HTTP services?

Comment: How do you connect with the PHP service? It could be the HTTPService doing that :) And indeed, check for the showBusyCursor attribute. Creating your own cursor to work-around the problem shouldn't be neccesary.

Comment: Doing my best not to sound like a complete moron here, but probably doing a pretty poor job. To create the connection to the PHP service, I went to Data->Connect to Data/Service... and then chose PHP from the wizard, specified my PHP file, and it installed Zend Framework, found all my functions in the PHP file, and allowed me to use them in the project. I looked around a bit, but can't seem to find where, in the program or otherwise, that I can check/modify the showBusyCursor attribute...any idea where I can set this attribute in Flash Builder 4 Beta 2?

Comment: Just as I suspected...I AM a moron. I found the attribute in the declaration. I just used the wizard (and am a total noob in Flash), so I didn't even know that declaration was there \**smacks forehead\**. Found that attribute and it was set to true, changed it to false and all is well, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm repeating my comment as an answer since it solved your issue, and adding a bit of detail. When you use the Data Connection wizard the default flag for showBusyCursor is "true" in order to prevent it you need to change this setting to "false".

I'm not sure what the FB4 wizard builds since I'm still using FB3, but if it's similar to the mxml httpService you just need to find the service in the .mxml file and you will see that attribute.

Now repeat after me. "All programmers make silly mistakes, especially when we are using new languages, I am no more of a moron than any other programmer" If, in a year, you look back on your code and don't say to yourself "what was I thinking" then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: In FB4, I found the solution within the <fx:Declarations> section. The service looks like this: <flash:FLASH id="fLASH" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="false"/>.  This is where I found the showBusyCursor attribute you were talking about.